# How to search for a word and then replace text after it using regular expressions in python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a script that will search through a html file and then replace the form action. So in this basic code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Forms</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
        <br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> 
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like the script to search for form action="login.php" but then only replace the login.php, with say newlogin.php. The key thing is that the form action might change from file to file, i.e. on another html file the login.php might be something totally different,  so the regular expression has to search for the form action= and replace the text after it (maybe using the " as limiters?)

My knowledge of regular expressions is pretty basic, for example I'd know how to replace just login.php:

```
(re.sub('login.php', 'newlogin.php', line))
```

but obviously it's no use as mentioned above if the login.php changes from file to file.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks all =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the re catch 2 groups, the form and everything leading up to the 1st quote after action, and the action content.

Use the 1st group for the replacement, followed by the new action:

```py
re.sub(r'(<form.*?action=")([^"]+)', r'\1newlogin.php',  content)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex, or just simple string manipulation. Just a test case.

```
for line in open("file"):
    if "form action" in line:
       line=line.rstrip()
       a=line.split('<form action="')
       a[-1] = '"newlogin" ' + a[-1].split()[-1]
       line = '<form action='.join(a)
    print line
```

Comment: thanks a lot ghostdog, not having to use regexs would simplify matters  a lot I think. I will look into this =) - (unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer =( )

Comment: as you are the original poster you can however accept it (check the flag in front of)

Answer (score 0):

You cant try this technique:

```
(<form[^>]*action=")[^"]*
```

pseudo-code:

```
regex.replace(input, pattern, concat(\1, new_value))
```

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=<form[^>]*action=")[^"]*
```

Comment: Just an FYI... `<form method="post" action="login.php">` will fail to match.

Comment: @Paul, forgot `*`. Check now.

Comment: In a few languages, this works. Python doesn't support variable width lookbehinds.  :)

Comment: @Paul, Are you sure? http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: From the docs... "The contained pattern must only match strings of some fixed length, meaning that abc or a|b are allowed, but a* and a{3,4} are not."

Comment: The general idea is solid though. Can you just ditch the lookbehind and capture the action content in a group?

Comment: @Paul, You mean `(<form[^>]*action=")[^"]*` replacing with: pseudo-code: `concat(group[1], new_value)`?